# An efficient way of constructing line animation

Tags: animation

I am trying to visualize the solution of [this leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/) by using `MatrixPlot`. Here is what I have now:

[image]

The steps of solving the problem is available in its [editorial solution](https://leetcode.com/articles/container-most-water/).

I use `Line` to draw the cross and `Circle` to draw the circle. Here's my code, it's messy because I hardcode many parameters (time, positions etc.)

Is there a way to visualize the solution with more simplicity and less code?

My code:

```
    piec[x_, top_, btm_] :=
      Piecewise[{{btm, x <= btm}, {x, x < top && x > btm}, {top, 
        x >= top}}]

    piecLine[a_, b_, c_, d_] :=
      Piecewise[{{Null, a == c && b == d}, {Line[{{a, b}, {c, d}}], 
        a != c || b != d}}]

    Manipulate[
      Show[MatrixPlot[
        Table[{Boole[i >= 1], Boole[i >= 2], Boole[i >= 3], Boole[i >= 4],
           Boole[i >= 5], Boole[i >= 6], Boole[i >= 7], Boole[i >= 8], 
          Boole[i >= 9], Boole[i >= 10]}, {i, 10}], Mesh -> All, 
        MeshStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], 
        ColorRules -> {1 -> GrayLevel[0.76], 0 -> Orange}],
       Table[Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t], 
          piecLine[j - a, 9.5 - a, piec[k, j + a, j - a], 
           piec[-j + k + 9.5, 9.5 + a, 9.5 - a]], 
          piecLine[j - a, 9.5 + a, piec[k, j + a, j - a], 
           piec[9.5 + j - k, 9.5 + a, 9.5 - a]]}], {j, 1.5, 8.5, 
         1}],   (*first row*)


       Table[Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t], 
          piecLine[9.5 - a, j - a, piec[-j + k + 9.5, 9.5 + a, 9.5 - a], 
           piec[k, j + a, j - a]]}], {j, 7.5, 1.5, -1}],
       Table[
        Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t],
          piecLine[9.5 - a, j + a, 
           9.5 - a + piec[k - j - 0.5 + a, 2 a, 0], 
           j + a - piec[k - j - 0.5 + a, 2 a, 0]]}], {j, 1.5, 7.5, 1}], (* first column *)

       Table[Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t],
          piecLine[j + 1 - a, 8.5 + a, 
           piec[k - 11.5 + 2.5, j + 1 + a, j + 1 - a], 
           piec[20 - k + j - 1.5, 8.5 + a, 8.5 - a]],
          piecLine[j + 1 - a, 8.5 - a, 
           piec[k - 11.5 + 2.5, j + 1 + a, j + 1 - a], 
           piec[k - 11.5 + 8.5 - j + 1.5, 8.5 + a, 8.5 - a]]}], {j, 1.5, 
         6.5, 1}],               (* second row *)

       Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t], 
         Circle[{9.5, 9.5}, 1.3 a, {0, piec[k, 2, 0] Pi}]}],
       Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t], 
         Circle[{9.5, 8.5}, 1.3 a, {0, piec[k - 4, 2, 0] Pi}]}],
       Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t], 
         Circle[{8.5, 8.5}, 1.3 a, {0, piec[k - 6, 2, 0] Pi}]}],
       Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t], 
         Circle[{7.5, 7.5}, 1.3 a, {0, piec[k - 8, 2, 0] Pi}]}]
       ], {k, 0, 20}];
```

Comment: I'll admit that I don't understand how your visualization is correlated with the problem you linked. Perhaps you could explain what the symbols mean etc.

Comment: The code appears to have errors in it.

Comment: You are missing values for `a` and `t`.

Answer (score 2):

You can tidy the code up a bit. Here I have:

- Replaced `piec` with the built-in `Clip`
- Replaced the piecewise function in `piecLine` with multiple definitions
- Defined `cross` and `nought` to do the drawing
- Replaced multiple `Graphics` expressions with a single one
- Replaced the matrix in `MatrixPlot` with a simpler alternative

.

```
a = 0.2;

piecLine[a_, b_, a_, b_] := {}
piecLine[a_, b_, c_, d_] := Line[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]

cross[p_, q_, t_] := {
  piecLine[p - a, q - a, p + Clip[t, {-a, a}], q + Clip[t, {-a, a}]],
  piecLine[p - a, q + a, p + Clip[t - 0.5, {-a, a}], q + Clip[0.5 - t, {-a, a}]]}

nought[pos_, t_] := Circle[pos, 1.3 a, {0, Clip[t, {0, 2}] Pi}]

background = MatrixPlot[LowerTriangularize@ConstantArray[1, {10, 10}],
   Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], 
   ColorRules -> {1 -> GrayLevel[0.76], 0 -> Orange}];

Manipulate[
 Show[background, Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[2],

    Table[cross[j, 9.5, k - j], {j, 1.5, 8.5}],
    Table[cross[9.5, j, k - j], {j, 1.5, 7.5}],
    Table[cross[j + 1, 8.5, k - j - 10], {j, 1.5, 6.5}],

    nought[{9.5, 9.5}, k],
    nought[{9.5, 8.5}, k - 4],
    nought[{8.5, 8.5}, k - 6],
    nought[{7.5, 7.5}, k - 8]

    }]], {k, 0, 20}]
```

The code is not fundamentally any different to your original, but I think it's easier to read this way.